# plotly: TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Tags: python, plotly

I have a problem with the project I'm currently working on, so I'm leaving a question.
The current contents are drawn in table format by sensor. But a few days ago, when I was working on something, I didn't know how to fix it, so I asked for help.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from bluepy import sensortag
import sys
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np

py.sign_in("smrlswja9963","94b4enXKYqyOu4iuPDGG")

time.sleep(1.0)

tag = sensortag.SensorTag('24:71:89:CC:53:00')
tag.IRtemperature.enable()
tag.humidity.enable()

stream1=py.Stream('liz9v2c0or')
stream1.open()

i=0     
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    dateTime = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    A = tag.IRtemperature.read()
    B = tag.humidity.read()
    tempt=A[0]
    humty=B[0]

    stream1.write({dateTime,tempt,humty})

    i+=1

    tag.waitForNotifications(3.0)     

table = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=["dateTime","tempt","humty"]),
    cells=dict(values=[[dateTime],[tempt],[humty]]),
    stream = dict(token='liz9v2c0or',))

data=[table]
py.iplot(table, filename="latex table")
```

After executing the following code, the following error occurred.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/do it.py", line 27, in <module>
    stream1.write({dateTime,tempt,humty})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py", line 632, in write
    stream_object.update(trace)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

In this case, the code that I draw the graph using plolty does not have a problem when receiving data from stream, but when I draw table plot.

How can I graph here?
I'm really curious. Please let me know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This exception means that you're trying to construct a dict from an iterable, and that iterable's first element is not a sequence. As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) explain, you can construct a dict two ways:

- From a mapping, or
- From an iterable of key-value pairs

So, if you try to construct it from, say, a set of numbers:

```
>>> dict({1, 2, 3})
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

… it's trying to use the first element as a key-value pair—that is, a sequence of 2 values—but there's no way to interpret the number `1` as a key-value pair, so it raises a `TypeError`.

---

Meanwhile, I know absolutely nothing about Plotly streaming but what's on [this page](https://help.plot.ly/streaming/), but this code is clearly wrong:

```
stream1.write({dateTime,tempt,humty})
```

I can't imagine why you'd want to stream a set.

Plus, the examples all have either a dict, or a string that's a JSON-encoding of a dict.

So, obviously, that API is expecting you to pass it either a dict or something you can feed to the dict constructor. But you're passing it a set. So, it feeds that set to the dict constructor, and gets this exception.

Since I have no idea what you're actually trying to do here, I have no idea *what* dict you should be sending here. But you definitely should be passing a dict.

---

Also, even if you fix this, based on the `sign_in` call, it looks like you're using Plotly Cloud. But, as the same page says:

> Streaming is no longer supported in Plotly Cloud.

So, if you're trying to use streaming with Plotly Cloud, then, even if you fix your code to make sense, it's probably still going to fail, just with an error from Plotly rather than a `TypeError` about passing nonsense.

Comment: So if I look at some of the code on the Google page and I've been working with stream on a flat cloud, isn't it supporting that graph?

Comment: @임종훈 I don’t know what “the Google page” is. And I don’t know what “a flat cloud” is. And I didn’t say graphing isn’t supported on the cloud, but that _streaming_ isn’t supported. So… I have no idea how to answer any of that.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep asking you.
First, I succeeded in drawing a straight graph by referring to the code at the following site, and now I can draw a straight graph and a table at the same time, and then I can use html for other websites. 
"https://smidgeonpigeon.wordpress.com/tag/python/"                        I drew a real time graph by referring to the code of the following contents and now I am going to draw it as a table. How should I fix it?

Comment: @임종훈 Well, the code in that example passes a dict every time it calls `write`. You're passing a set. My answer explains why that makes a difference. I still don't know what you're trying to graph here. Maybe you want the dict `{'dateTime': dateTime, 'tempt': tempt, 'humty': humty}`, maybe you want something different. Only you know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, let me explain what I want to do
So what I want to do is I want to get the data in real time and draw it in the form of a table so I can type the code I asked you about
I started out with the idea of how to get started with this job in real time from Tinsor tag and draw the corresponding graph.
When I initially assign work, I can stream the work to draw the graph
But what I wanted to do was to import the graph in the form of the graph into the other web and import the data from the side. It started with a thought.
How do you think we should change that?  Please let me know. I beg you

Answer (score 0):

Going by the exception you have posted the below line is the problem -

`stream1.write({dateTime,tempt,humty})`

Without quoting the documentation - we have to understand that the dictionary data structure in Python works just like a regular dictionary. In a regular dictionary - when you search a word`(key)`, you get the meaning of that word `(value)`.

If you look at the above code snippet - you are passing 3 parameters to the dictionary object. The syntax is wrong as Python is expecting a `key:value` pair. Hence the correct syntax should be -

`stream1.write({dateTime1: tempt, dateTime2: humty})`