# Similarity with Doc2Vec

Tags: python, doc2vec

I'm following a Gensim tutorial for Doc2Vec: https://medium.com/@mishra.thedeepak/doc2vec-simple-implementation-example-df2afbbfbad5

Now, after reaching the end, I'd like to compute similarity scores for the docs in training data. Those docs vectors are given by `model.docvecs[0]`, `model.docvecs[1]` etc

But when I try to run for example

```
cossim(model.docvecs[0], model.docvecs[1])
```

I get TypeError `cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`. How can I calculate the cosine similarity between the documents in the training data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220615/plotly-typeerror-cannot-convert-dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-to-a-seq) is a good explanation of what that error means.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449019/how-to-use-cosssim-in-gensim) is a good explanation of what exactly is happening in your case.

So, as mentioned under the documentation of [keyed vectors](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Doc2VecKeyedVectors), you should use `model.docvecs.distance(0, 1)` to compute cosine distance between your two documents.

Comment: ```distance()``` from which package? It doesn't seem to be imported by gensim.matutils or exist in base Python

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't tried the solution. I have updated it now. Can you give it a try?

Comment: this worked! I don't find the documentation very clear on this point though. What if I infer one vector using ```model.infer_vector``` (not in the training-set) and then want its cosine similarity, either with another inferred vector or with a training-data vector?

Comment: That's great. I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488877/finding-the-distance-between-doctag-and-infer-vector-with-gensim-doc2vec) covers that.